# American apostrophe clears form input

Tags: php, json

`’` this kind of apostrophe ruins my input which is saved to database. I've tried

```
$GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1]=str_replace("’", "'",  

$GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1]);
```

So changing `’` to `'` with no results I still get empty field.
This value with apostrophe is shown just fine but after sending it with

```
 <input type="hidden" name="GeneralChangeDescriptions" value="'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($GeneralChangeDescriptions)).'">
```

it no longer is visible the whole input is blank is there any way to fix this?

Update:

After fiddling a bit with code I found out that json_encode completely wipes my input after sending are there any easy solutions?

Comment: "ruins your input"? Ruins **HOW**?

Comment: the input is **BLANK** nothing is saved to the database

Comment: so... basic debugging: view the page source, see if that hidden element actually contains anything, then start backtracking and see where the value vanishes.

Comment: it vanishes after using htmlspecialchars(json_encode

Comment: so again, start back tracking. maybe it was htmlspecialchars. maybe it was json_encode... try each separately.

Comment: json_encode screws things up

Comment: then check json_last_error() for why it failed.

Comment: I got 5 as a result of this

Comment: And which of [the constants returned](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) has a value of 5 in your version of PHP?

Comment: right after <input type="hidden" name="GeneralChangeDescriptions" value="'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($GeneralChangeDescriptions)).'"> i used json_last_error() and i received 5